# File path not being loaded despite it showing up in file list array when it's simply printed out

Tags: ruby, require

I have a weird behavioral problem involving the following code:

```
ignore_list = %w(boot boot_as_service required test)
info_file = ''
file_list = []
Dir.chdir(__dir__){
  Dir.glob('**/*.rb') do | file|
    t = file.split('/').last.split('.')
    f_name = t.first
    f_type = t.last
    # puts [f_name,f_type].inspect
    next unless f_type == 'rb'
    next if ignore_list.include?(f_name)
    info_file = file.gsub('/','\\') and next if f_name == 'info'
    file_list << file.gsub('/','\\')
  end
}
file_list.unshift(info_file)
```

I then require each file in the `file_list` one after another like so:

```
file_list.each do |file|
  puts "loading #{File.basename(file)}"
  require  __dir__.gsub('/','\\')  +  "\\#{file.gsub('lib\\','')}"
end
```

When I just run the code and just print out the array I get :

```
["gg-web-opsboard\\info.rb", "gg-web-opsboard\\data\\data.rb", "gg-web-opsboard\\helpers\\helpers.rb", "gg-web-opsboard\\main.rb", "gg-web-opsboard\\routing\\a
ctions.rb", "test.rb"]
```

like I expect but, when I install my application as a gem, and try to run the command that starts it, I get this: 
`<class:GG_Web_OpsBoard>': uninitialized constant Sinatra::GG_Web_OpsBoard::Actions (NameError)`

and the files loaded are:

```
Starting Sinatra app on 0.0.0.0:3000
booting...
loading info.rb
loading data.rb
loading helpers.rb
loading main.rb
```

So my question, is why does `actions.rb` get skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do to simplify your code.

Starting with your code:

```
ignore_list = %w(boot boot_as_service required test)
info_file = ''
file_list = []
Dir.chdir(__dir__){
  Dir.glob('**/*.rb') do | file|
    t = file.split('/').last.split('.')
    f_name = t.first
    f_type = t.last
    # puts [f_name,f_type].inspect
    next unless f_type == 'rb'
    next if ignore_list.include?(f_name)
    info_file = file.gsub('/','\\') and next if f_name == 'info'
    file_list << file.gsub('/','\\')
  end
}
file_list.unshift(info_file)
```

The first thing is that Ruby doesn't care whether your filenames on Windows use reversed slashes or forwards slashes. This is from [the IO documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html):

> Ruby will convert pathnames between different operating system conventions if possible. For instance, on a Windows system the filename "/gumby/ruby/test.rb" will be opened as "\gumby\ruby\test.rb".

In other words, save yourself the trouble of converting to backslashes in paths, and let Ruby deal with it. That reduces the lines

```
info_file = file.gsub('/','\\') and next if f_name == 'info'
file_list << file.gsub('/','\\')
```

to

```
info_file = file and next if f_name == 'info'
file_list << file
```

The first of those lines can be made more readable. Using `and next` with a trailing `if` conditional is an attempt to reduce the code into a single line, but that shouldn't be a goal as it doesn't improve performance or maintainability. Instead, I'd use:

```
if f_name == 'info'
  info_file = file
  next 
end
```

The line

```
next unless f_type == 'rb'
```

can be removed entirely because

```
Dir.glob('**/*.rb')
```

will only return files with `.rb` as their extension.

Let's look at what you're doing with

```
ignore_list = %w(boot boot_as_service required test)
```

It's an array and you want to check to see if files are in that list using `include?`. Each time you check, that array has to be walked, which can become costly, either as the size of the array grows or the number of files being checked increases. Instead, use a [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html), which also has the [`include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-include-3F) method, but is a lot faster than Array's because a Set is based on a hash, so it's random access, instead of sequentially accessed. Also, because `ignore_list` is acting like a constant, I'd make it one:

```
include 'set'
IGNORE_LIST = %w(boot boot_as_service required test).to_set
```

Looking at

```
t = file.split('/').last.split('.')
f_name = t.first
f_type = t.last
next if IGNORE_LIST.include?(f_name)
```

it's pretty convoluted when you're only trying to get the basename and extension from the file. I'd do this:

```
f_type = File.extname(file)
f_name = File.basename(file, f_type)
next if IGNORE_LIST.include?(f_name)
```

The first two lines do this:

```
f_type = File.extname(file)           # => ".rb"
f_name = File.basename(file, f_type)  # => "file"
```

It doesn't matter that `f_type` now has a leading `.` since we already know that testing `f_type == 'rb'` wasn't necessary. Instead, [`basename`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-basename) can use it to strip off the extension returned by [`extname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-extname), leaving the name of the file minus the extension.

That leaves the code looking like:

```
include 'set'
IGNORE_LIST = %w(boot boot_as_service required test).to_set

info_file = ''
file_list = []

Dir.chdir(__dir__) do

  Dir.glob('**/*.rb') do | file|

    f_type = File.extname(file)
    f_name = File.basename(file, f_type)
    next if IGNORE_LIST.include?(f_name)

    if f_name == 'info'
      info_file = file
      next 
    end

    file_list << file

  end
end

file_list.unshift(info_file)
```

That's a pretty reasonable reduction of complexity and results in code that is more readable and maintainable I think. But, there's something about Ruby and how it lets us treat arrays like sets that is useful. Consider this:

```
IGNORE_LIST = %w(boot boot_as_service required test).map{ |s| "#{ s }.rb" }

files = %w[a.rb boot.rb boot_as_service.rb q.rb required.rb s.rb test.rb]
```

If `files` was the output of `Dir.glob('**/*.rb')`, and `IGNORE_LIST` transparently included the extensions, then we can easily find what files exist in the directory that should *not* be ignored:

```
files - IGNORE_LIST # => ["a.rb", "q.rb", "s.rb"]
```

Knowing that, the code reduces to:

```
IGNORE_LIST = %w(boot boot_as_service required test info).map{ |s| "#{ s }.rb" }

file_list = []

Dir.chdir(__dir__) do
  file_list = Dir.glob('**/*.rb') - IGNORE_LIST
end

file_list << 'info.rb'
```

The only problem is the names `Dir.glob` returns have paths, so that has to be accommodated. Creating a hash where the keys are the base names of the files would help. `group_by` makes that easy:

```
files = %w[/foo/a.rb /foo/b.rb /bar/a.rb /bar/b.rb]
files_by_basenames = files.group_by{ |f| File.basename(f) }
files_by_basenames # => {"a.rb"=>["/foo/a.rb", "/bar/a.rb"], "b.rb"=>["/foo/b.rb", "/bar/b.rb"]}
```

We can easily grab the keys:

```
files_by_basenames.keys # => ["a.rb", "b.rb"]
```

Which puts us back where we can test for desirable files in chunks since all the desirable full-pathname files are grouped in the values as arrays. Here's some code to think about:

```
files = %w[/foo/a.rb /foo/b.rb /foo/boot.rb /bar/a.rb /bar/b.rb /bar/test.rb]
files_by_basenames = files.group_by{ |f| File.basename(f) }
files_by_basenames # => {"a.rb"=>["/foo/a.rb", "/bar/a.rb"], "b.rb"=>["/foo/b.rb", "/bar/b.rb"], "boot.rb"=>["/foo/boot.rb"], "test.rb"=>["/bar/test.rb"]}

files_by_basenames.keys # => ["a.rb", "b.rb", "boot.rb", "test.rb"]

good_files = files_by_basenames.keys - %w[boot.rb test.rb] # => ["a.rb", "b.rb"]

files_by_basenames.values_at(*good_files) # => [["/foo/a.rb", "/bar/a.rb"], ["/foo/b.rb", "/bar/b.rb"]]

files_by_basenames.values_at(*good_files).flatten # => ["/foo/a.rb", "/bar/a.rb", "/foo/b.rb", "/bar/b.rb"]
```

Putting the code back together:

```
IGNORE_LIST = %w(boot boot_as_service required test info).map{ |s| "#{ s }.rb" }

file_list = []

Dir.chdir(__dir__) do
  files_by_basenames = Dir.glob('**/*.rb').group_by{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  good_filenames = files_by_basenames.keys - IGNORE_LIST
  file_list = files_by_basenames.values_at(*good_filenames).flatten
end

file_list << 'info.rb'
```

Because I don't know what paths you'll be seeing for your hierarchy, it's hard to say what pathname or names should be in front of 'info.rb', but even that can be quickly figured out using:

```
IGNORE_LIST = %w(boot boot_as_service required test).map{ |s| "#{ s }.rb" }

file_list = []

Dir.chdir(__dir__) do
  files_by_basenames = Dir.glob('**/*.rb').group_by{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  good_filenames = files_by_basenames.keys - IGNORE_LIST
  info_files = files_by_basenames.delete('info.rb')
  file_list = files_by_basenames.values_at(*good_filenames).flatten
end

file_list += info_files
```

"info" was removed from `IGNORE_LIST` so we could capture it into `info_files`, then append them after the fact.

That's untested, but it looks about right.

Comment: Thanks. I'd say it's super verbose, and I was afraid it was a candidate for "TL;DR" but if it helped that's good. It's cool to see what Ruby can do with a little code when using things like `group_by` and manipulating arrays using sets.

Comment: I haven't read it all yet but I'll probably go through it  over the weekend. Nah, it's not long, just indepth, and that's good as I want to learn better ways to do things, part of that is learning how to do things and I can't if I don't know how. Part of what I've been doing is iteratively improving my app, one way is to dynamically load all the main code files, doing that plus a bunch of other stuff means I can have a more generic code base that can then be used in other projects rather than just build it and then start from scratch, anything that can make it less hard-coded is a good thing.

Comment: Well, there's no guarantee that it'll work for your situation, but the tricks should get you a lot closer, and make your code more concise. Dealing with hashes and arrays as sets is a different way of thinking, but once you think in those terms you can chew up data really quickly. I programmed in Perl for years, and it was amazing what I could do with a little code; I just transferred that knowledge to Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised what the problem was, it wasn't skipping `actions.rb` at all, it just wasn't getting to it, I just have to ensure that `main.rb` gets loaded last is all. 
I can do this by changing `info_files` into a hash and then doing:

```
file_list.unshift(ordered_files[:info]) << ordered_files[:main]
```